# Chromedriver fails on Windows 10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Dears stackoverflowers.

I have stuck with Selenium tests run locally.

- ChromeDriver v2.7.236900 (32)
- Chrome version Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)
- Operation system is Windows 10 (64)

I just run this code:

```
open("http://anypage.com");
```

and get an error:

```
Using CustomChromeDriverProvider
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.7.236900) on port 3431

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'aliakseiPC', ip: '10.6.170.169', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\ALIAKS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10772_6183}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4a396df3b78d4da050e77cc00f493f3a
```

[image]

Comment: uninstall any installed plugins and try.